# problem to update maven to 3.6.3 on MacOS

Tags: java, macos, maven, maven-3

I have maven 3.6.1 installed on my Mac

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.1 (d66c9c0b3152b2e69ee9bac180bb8fcc8e6af555; 2019-04-05T00:30:29+05:30)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.1/libexec
Java version: 11.0.9, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.9.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.14.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

To update mac to 3.6.3, what I did was I have downloaded latest 3.6.3 version and move the apache-maven-3.6.3 to /Applications folder and have set the Home PATH in my ~/.bash_profile file as shown below:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/sbin:$PATH"
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.9.jdk/Contents/Home
export M2_HOME=/Applications/apache-maven-3.6.3
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

and $source ~/.bash_profile

But still when I run $mvn -version I am getting 3.6.1 only, I even restarted the system too.

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.1 (d66c9c0b3152b2e69ee9bac180bb8fcc8e6af555; 2019-04-05T00:30:29+05:30)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.1/libexec
Java version: 11.0.9, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.9.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.14.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Why my maven version is not pointing to 3.6.3? How can I fix it? I do not want to go for brew install option.

Why my Maven home was pointing to  `/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.1/libexec` instead `/Applications` folder path? I already had this maven installed on my system, so I was not sure, how it was installed and how that path was set to `/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.1/libexec`. Now I want to change this to the my latest maven folder in /Applications.

Comment: Remove M2_HOME etc. only add the binary directory in your PATH... furthermore remove the Maven installation via brew ... or upgrade the installation via brew only ....

Answer (score 2):

you have to put the location of the new mvn before the existing one

```
export PATH=$M2_HOME/bin:$PATH
```